# Question was closed even after editing and resolving all issues

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Two days ago I asked a question on Stack Overflow, which, admittedly, was lacking in clarity and details, and the code example I included wasn't functional, so it was downvoted and voted to be closed.

After a comment made me aware of these issues, I edited the question to include a minimal reproducible example and gave more details about the issue I was having, but after the edit my question was downvoted again and closed.

I'd like to know if there's anything else I can add to the question or anything needs further clarification for the question to reopened.

[Here's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76569159/range-search-on-a-3d-kd-tree-fails-to-find-nodes-within-the-specified-range)

Comment: I'm no SME in that tag, but that seems like a lot of code for reproducing your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can say that you've "resolved all issues". I'm no C++ expert, but your question could still use a lot of debugging information including the specifics of what you've done to debug the situation, what you've found in your attempts,... just a lot more and higher quality information, would definitely help, and certainly won't hurt.

Comment: Also, I hope that you are aware of the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/522444), and if not please check the link. Understand that any question or answer highlighted in a meta question will undergo more attention and even scrutiny, and this can result in increased voting on the question or answer, sometimes positive, and sometimes negative, depending.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'll try to provide more info, and reduce the code as much as I can, in future edits.

Comment: Don't just reduce the code though. Best to create and post a [mre] (please see the link) along with debugging information, if possible.

Comment: The last edit that made it even possible to answer your question, was made essentially, the moment the question was closed based on the timeline (within 15 minutes).  Had the question contained a full and complete MRE from the start the question wouldn't have been closed more than likely. You can of course make an edit to your question, indicate the question is ready to be reviewed by clicking the appropriate checkbox, for it to be potentially reopened by the community.  How long that will take depends on the community.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### We don't fix code here; we answer questions

This is the elephant in the room. The initial comment exchange is enlightening: you are asked to provide a specific question, and you respond by removing the (perfectly valid) language tag - because you don't think you have a question that's about C++ itself. Instead, you have C++ code, and it doesn't do what you want it to do, and you want someone else to tell you something that will enable you to fix it. I did understand the situation correctly this far, yes?

That's extremely common - probably the overwhelming majority of new questions nowadays are like this. People encounter an issue when writing some code, and expect that, by writing "how do I fix this code?" or similar - or by at least describing the problem clearly - they are "asking a question" that is "about programming", and thus working within the Stack Overflow mission statement (as described in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.").

**However, that really isn't what we have in mind**.

What you (and countless others) really have here is a *request* to [*debug*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) the code. In other words, you want us to find out *what and where* the problem is, first, and *then* tell you how to fix it.

Figuring out the "what and where" is supposed to be your job. Questions are about specific, concrete, already-identified problems. Requests are about tasks, which includes the task of finding and identifying the problem (debugging the code).

On the [How to Ask help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), we link a [basic guide to debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It's written by Eric Lippert, a [relatively well known](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) Stack Overflow user with a pretty impressive CV.

### About "debugging questions"

When the starting point is code that doesn't work, generally we describe this as a "debugging question". I personally don't like this term, because it falsely implies that we might do debugging on behalf of the OP.

After discovering a problem with code, if you want to ask about it on Stack Overflow, what [should you do next](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)? Here is a quick guide:

- Identify, on a conceptual level, **what things are supposed to happen**, in order, when the code runs.
- **Verify which** things happen correctly and which don't, by **carefully checking what actually happens** when the code runs (using an actual debugger program, logging, unit testing, or any other methods that seem appropriate).
- **Isolate only the first part that goes wrong** (because Stack Overflow questions need to be about **one** thing), and sets up a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for that part. That is: code that can be *copied and pasted, without adding or changing anything*, to make the *exact* apparent problem occur *directly* - with as little setup as possible.

  For example, if there's a specific function that does the wrong thing with certain inputs, then create code that produces non-working (but "valid", i.e. expected to work) inputs *as simply as possible*, and then calls the function. If the problem is wrong output, follow up with *as simple code as possible* to highlight what is wrong with the output.
- If possible, **iterate** the above process to break it down further. If the non-working function is calling other functions, maybe the problem is caused by one of them? Test those individually.

Once a *specific* problem is *identified, located and made reproducible*, then there is a valid Stack Overflow question. This is no longer a "what [is wrong]?" or "where [is the bug]?" question. It is a "why [does this specific thing do something different from my expectation]?" question. There are two main categories of useful, valuable question on Stack Overflow: "why" questions like these, and "how[-to]" questions.

### Focus, suitability and customization

Questions that go directly from "I have an issue with my code" to being posted on Stack Overflow generally get closed for either of two reasons:

- **Needs debugging details**: this can be true because there's *too much* code shown as well as too little. Take the time to [write a shorter letter](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/04/28/shorter-letter/). A "minimal reproducible example" should be *minimal*.
- **Needs more focus**: generally, because there's more than one thing wrong with the code, but also because we are being asked to do multiple things - find the problem, and *then* explain it.

At this point, you might wonder: why not then just "focus" the question specifically on the "please find the problem" part, and have OP assume responsibility for fixing it? That's simple: such questions are *not useful for the goal of building a library*. And do keep in mind that this *is* the goal; Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum or a help desk** (this is what the first commenter was trying to explain). Questions here *need to be able to solve someone else's problem, not just your own, at least in theory*.

Try to imagine what would be necessary in order for such a question to help others. They would effectively need to have the exact same problem *in the same code* - because if the code were any different, the process of finding the problem would play out differently. Even if that were the case, how would the other person *find* the right Q&A? It's not as if we can expect to copy and paste entire pages of code into a search engine, and find someone else experiencing the same problem with something that's structured exactly the same way but maybe has different variable names or something.

And *even then*, how likely is it that the same problem, with the same code, could be experienced by two different people, who are then able to *understand the same explanation, while neither one actually needs* to be told how to fix it? Generally speaking, a problem that could be understood and fixed by everyone who would ask about it... is not actually a problem. It's simply the result of not spending time to look for what is wrong. Generally, these are covered by the "typo or not reproducible" closure reason.

### Your specific case

Let's see what you're asking:

> The issue is that the code does not find nodes which I know to be in the specified range. Sometimes it doesn't even find a single node, including the "node" parameter itself which is inserted into the tree beforehand.

First off, it makes absolutely no sense to say "sometimes" here, because the code is expected to be deterministic. You hard-coded the input tree, after all. Are you actually getting consistent results from the code shown, with the hard-coded input and all? (If not, did you try to check for undefined behaviour?) Is 'the "node" parameter itself' found when you try this example? If so, can you instead easily create an example where it *isn't*? (How many nodes do you actually need in the input tree in order to create a reliable failure? What needs to be true about the tree's structure, in order for the search to fail?)

For that matter, **did you verify that this code reproduces the problem?** I see the search function is called like `node->withinDistance(node, new KdNode({1, 1, 1}), 1, within_range);`, but declared like `void KdNode::withinDistance(KdNode* rootNode, KdNode* node, const double distance, std::vector<KdNode*>& within_range, int axis)`. Where is the initial value for `axis` supposed to come from? I don't see a default value.

> I'm trying to implement a Kd-tree and I have to find all nodes within a certain distance of any given node.

**This is at least three tasks:**

- implement the data structures necessary to represent the tree
- actually create a tree
- find the appropriate nodes within the tree

It's your responsibility, before asking, to figure out which goes wrong.

Given your `KdNode` structure, can you create tree nodes? Is that sufficient for representing a tree? (It is, but you should make sure you can present that argument yourself before continuing.)

Does the code that's intended to create the tree, successfully instantiate nodes? Are they connected to each other in the expected way? Did you try to check this? How? For example, if you create two nodes and then `insert` one into the other, and then check the pointer values stored in each node, do they look like what you expect? (*Do you know what to expect?*)

For the actual search part, it looks to me that your approach is to store nodes into a vector of node pointers, passed by non-const reference; you pass a pointer to the node representing the current position in the tree and a pointer to a node to search for, and it uses recursion. Yes? So. Did you test the base case? Did you check what happens when a recursive call is made? Did you check what recursive calls get made? For a simple input tree, can you explain exactly what calls you expect to be made, and why? If you try that, and trace the execution, does it match your expectation? Did you try, for example, using logging to see which nodes are "visited"? Does every node get visited exactly once, as it should? If nodes are missed, do you notice any pattern as to which ones?

Aside from all of that, did you attempt *linting* - i.e., looking for things that seem inherently suspicious? For example, are values used consistently, especially WRT how many levels of indirection are assumed? (Hint: the code for the search function says both `(*rootNode->left)` and `rootNode->left`; does that make sense? What do you expect is the order of operations for `(*rootNode->left)`? Did you try to verify that?) Did you enable compiler warnings, or check IDE suggestions? (I haven't used C++ recently enough to be sure if this is the, or a, problem. But it stands out.)

How about the fact that the code constantly needs to dereference pointers in order to use `operator[]` - did you consider passing the nodes by reference instead? (Did you realize that all the nodes allocated with `new` within `main` represent memory leaks?) Also, the parameter names don't seem to make sense. There is a `KdNode* rootNode`, but it represents the current node in the search. As far as I can tell, at all times the root node of the tree is represented by `this` (since the function is a member function, and the recursive calls all call this function implicitly upon `this`). Was that intended? Does it actually make sense to use a separate parameter for this, rather than making the method calls upon the child nodes? Does the algorithm actually need to remember what the actual root node of the entire tree is? The dissonance between the names and the apparent operation, points at issues in the thought process behind the code, which may point at understanding what was actually written incorrectly.

Comment: I think because most of my other questions happened to be specific questions and not "how to debug" questions, I wasn't aware of the distinction. I'll avoid asking this type of question in the future. Thanks for the detailed response.